# The system cannot find the path specified after os.chdir('..')

Tags: python

I have a python script here that copy images in multiple times, the first copying of image was a success but the second one gave this error. i know for sure that i changed my dir up one level or i did it in a wrong way? any ideas?

```
 os.chdir(path)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'my_images/babesia divergen
```

this is my code

```
import os
import shutil

for file in os.listdir("my_images/"):
    path='my_images/' + file
    os.chdir(path)
    cwd=os.getcwd()
    print(cwd)
    images=os.listdir(cwd)
    a = 0
    while a < 2:
        a = a + 1
        shutil.copy2(images[0],os.path.splitext(images[0])[0]+str(a)+os.path.splitext(images[0])[1])
        print(os.path.splitext(images[0])[0],a,os.path.splitext(images[0])[1])
    os.chdir('..')
    cwd2=os.getcwd()
    print(cwd2)
```

this is the output after

```
C:\Users\Polaius-Work\Desktop\New folder (2)\my_images\ascaris lumbricodes
ascaris lumbricodes 1 .jpg
ascaris lumbricodes 2 .jpg
C:\Users\Polaius-Work\Desktop\New folder (2)\my_images
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "duplicate_images.py", line 10, in <module>
    os.chdir(path)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'my_images/babesia divergen'
```

so clearly the `os.chdir('')` is working but but it dont recognize the second folder

Comment: Are any of the subdirectories in `my_images/` actually symlinks?

Comment: yes, there are 70 folders inside of `my_images/`

Comment: But are they symlinks?  Or just plain subdirectories?

Comment: just plain subdirectories

Comment: Are there any files in `my_images/` ? Can yuo run the script again printing out `path` before calling `os.chdir(path)` and then verify that `path` is a directory you are able to change into?

Comment: i've print out the path like this `print(path)` and gave me this error`my_images/babesia divergen
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "duplicate_images.py", line 11, in <module>
    os.chdir(path)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'my_images/babesia divergen'`

Comment: What is `my_images/babesia divergen` - is it something other than a directory?

Comment: On the previous loop iteration, was the output of `print(cwd2)` as expected?